# Vaadin 10 Secure Login / Security

Tags: java, security, vaadin

i want to start a Vaadin 10 Website and i want to have users to login to my site. How can i do this easily in Vaadin 10? I don’t want to make many html/css files, because i mainly use Java, and don’t know much html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Full Stack Spring starter](https://vaadin.com/start/v10-full-stack-spring) contains an example login page with Spring Security.

Comment: Thank you, im so sorry that i haven't seen this earlier. I thought all demos were made with Vaadin 8 :(

Comment: If you need some more details - especially when it comes to a Java-only solution - you can check https://vaadin.com/tutorials/securing-your-app-with-spring-security